# moveTaskToBack vs super.onBackPressed() in case of single activity

Tags: android

My project has a single `activity` and multiple `fragments`.Two in `ViewPager` and two to replace them. I have overridden `onBackPress` to check if I have more than one fragment in backstack, else I am doing `moveTaskToBack(true).` As there is only one activity, will it work exactly like `super.onBackPress` in case of back press?